# Change value of clock with circular slider in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uislider

I am working on a circular timer in iOS. The circle should contain a 24 hour cycle.

The picture below shows how i intend to change the time of the timer.

[image]

Instead of the position in degrees of the slider, I want to display the time accordingly to the position of the slider, but I'm kinda struggling to find the right formula. Does anyone have an idea how to tacke this?

Thank you in advance!
Granit

Comment: Is the code for this control posted anywhere? It looks awesome!

Comment: Just stumbled across this again. Did you ever post this control anywhere? It's really, really cool and I could use it in a current project!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trick some mathematical formulas;

like **360 / 24 = 15**, it means for 1 hour it rotates 15 degree,
so calculate for the others:

```
1 hour = 15 degree
2 hours = (15 * 2) = 30 degree and so on....
...
24 hours = (15 * 24) = 360 degree.
```

So if you get 273 value, it means

```
273/24 = int (11.375) = 11 hours
```

Comment: I like this answer, but in case he wants finer control of the timer (increments less than 1 hour), you might want to show him that, too. Good answer!